# Comic about a man on the run who helps a lost girl and encounters a woman who can see into the future

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, episode-identification

In the early seventies DC reprinted a story as a second or third feature in one of their comics. It was possibly a National story from the forties or fifties about a man on the run from the law. He's a good man, wrongly accused (though of what I cannot recall), who comes to the aid of a lost and scared young girl. He buys the girl a meal (the dialogue "Boy, you sure can put away that milk," rings in my memory) and afterward, with the girl, helps an old woman cross a busy city street. The woman thanks them and tells the girl she we receive three wishes followed by a panel in which she stares up into our hero's eyes and tells him, "And you, young man. Your troubles will pass."

This cheers up the girl considerably, who believes in the magic of the old woman's predictions. After the first wish comes true, the girl wishes for a doll or doll house she sees in a store window. Our hero, who I think is named Johnny, can't bear to see the girl revert to her sad state and buys it for her with the last of his money. The third wish is, of course, for the girl to be reunited with her parents. Somehow Johnny returns the girl to her parents and is either cleared of wrongdoing or his innocence is alluded to. The last panel sees Johnny walking away down a path with his back to us as the author assures us this is the first of many adventures he will have.

I read this comic over 40 years ago and I can still see the artwork in my mind as I type this. I'd love to know what comic this is.

Comment: How do you know it was DC?

Comment: @kingledion, at the time I read this comic, I was pretty much only reading DC titles. I would not discover Marvel and other comic publishers until I got a bit older. That being said, the mind can play tricks after a number of decades go by.